# Why should I specify a branch in semantic-release?

Tags: semantic-release

In *semantic-release* it's possible to specify a [branch](https://semantic-release.gitbook.io/semantic-release/usage/configuration#branch). For this, the documentation only states:

> The branch on which releases should happen.

What effect has this property? What happens if I do not use it? What happens if I use it, and run semantic-release on the specified branch, respectively, what happens if I run it on a different branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option defines the branch from which semantic-release will make releases.
If you don't set it it will automatically set to the default: `master`.

When semantic-release runs, if the CI job has been triggered on this branch (due to a commit being merged or pushed) it will make a release. IF the CI job was triggered on a different branch, semantic-release will do nothing and log that nothing has to be done as the current branch is not the release branch.